# Есть ли лайвхук у *ngIf?

Tags: angular

Ситуация следующая:
Есть у меня компонент, со структурой такого рода:

```
<app>
 <ng-container *ngIf="flag">
  <component-one> </component-one>
  <component-two> </component-two>
  <component-three> </component-three>
 </ng-container>
</app>
```

Есть сервис (**serviceGeneral**), который содержится в себе общую форму (formgroup).

В app компоненте в определённом методе **flag** меняется на true. После смены флага на true, соответственно, компоненты рендерятся (*ngIf становится true). При инициализации каждого компонента в общий сервис большой формы добавляется соответствующий formgroup (то есть, при инициализации компонента component-one, в общую форму добавляется поле формгруп этого компонента).
После смены флага flag на true я указываю логику для формы **serviceGeneral**.

**Проблема**: после смены флага компоненты ещё не отрендерись (из-за чего не добавились новые поля в общую форму) и поэтому я не могу обработать форму.

**Решение**: обернуть в setTimeout() свою логику, после изменения флага.

**Вопрос**: Есть ли изящнее методы решения моей проблемы? Без setTimeout ? Или это лучшее решение?

```
method() {
 this.flag = true;
 let groups = this.generalFormService.form;
 ...
}
```

Моё решение:

```
method() {
 this.flag = true;
 setTimeout( () => {
   let groups = this.generalFormService.form;
 }, 0);
 ...
}
```

Comment: почему в принципе не делать все эти вещи через rxjs и асинхронные потоки + генерацию событий? я не помню вовсе когда я последний раз использовал setTimeout..... складывается впечатление что angular ты учишь, а доку rx'a пропустил внаглую ))) :D

Comment: @overthesanity Извините, можете подсказать лучшее решение в данном случае, без каких-либо значительных внесений изменений не в app компоненты (то есть без componet-one и тд)? Я думал asynk await навесить, но не знал, на что...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Краеугольный камень Angular - это RxJS. Молоток уже поставляется с фреймворком, бОльшую часть проблем можно решать через Rx.

Здесь в любом случае тебе придется изменять все компоненты и сервис, иначе изначально логика заложена неправильно. Как говорил Бен Леш: "Если вы используете `setTimeout`, значит вы что-то делаете не так". В какой-то степени я с ним согласен, я сам, лично, не помню когда использовать последний раз `setTimeout`.

3 компонента не должны взаимодействовать с формой сервиса напрямую, для этого должен быть в сервисе какой-то метод:

```
this.generalFormService.form.addControl(...); // неправильно
this.generalFormService.addControl(...); // правильно
```

Если в другом классе есть метод, изолирующий определенную логику, то в дальнейшем изменения придется делать только в этом методе, а не во всех компонентах.

Далее если ты знаешь сколько у тебя дочерних компонентов, то можно просто в сервисе сделать генератор событий, который будет эмиттить значение после того, как 3 компонента добавят контролы, а в родительском компоненте на него подписаться:

```
class GeneralFormService {
  form$ = new Subject<void>();

  form = new FormGroup();

  addControl(...) {
    this.form.addControl(...);
    this.form$.next();
  }
}

class ParentComponent {
  flag = false;

  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(generalFormService: GeneralFormService) {
    generalFormService.form$
      .pipe(
        // 3 - кол-во компонентов, которые взаимодействуют с сервисом
        bufferCount(3),
        map(() => generalFormService.form),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe(form => {
        console.log(form);
      });
  }

  method() {
    this.flag = true;
  }
}
```

Если дочерних компонентов много и ты не знаешь какие из них взаимодействуют с сервисом, то можно просто получить доступ к `ng-container` и декорировать сеттер:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="flag" #container>
      ...
    </ng-container>
  `
})
class ParentComponent {
  flag = false;

  @ViewChild('container')
  set container(container: undefined | ElementRef<Comment>) {
    // если `container = undefined`, значит `ngIf=false`
    if (container) {
      console.log(this.generalFormService.form);
    }
  }

  constructor(private generalFormService: GeneralFormService) {}

  method() {
    this.flag = true;
  }
}
```

Я не знаю какую версию Angular ты используешь, это нужно указывать в вопросе, если 8, то нужно будет добавить в декоратор опцию `{ static: false }`.

---

Опять же, все эти примеры выше не есть бест практис, это просто косвенное решение твоей проблемы. Продумывай это все заранее и проблем будет возникать гораздо меньше

---

А вообще вместо `ng-container` можно использовать какой-то свой компонент и проджектить дочерние компоненты через `ng-content`. В самом компоненте создать метод `ngAfterContentInit` и какой-то генератор событий:

```
@Output() childrenRendered = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

Генерить событие в этом методе:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  this.childrenRenfered.emit();
}
```

И слушать его выше:

```
<app-some-wrapper *ngIf="flag" (childrenRendered)="childrenRendered()">
  <component-one></component-one>
  ...
</app-some-wrapper>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за толковый развёрнутый ответ!